# Cannot connect to server(WAMP, phpmyadmin), connecting VS to database?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssms

I am trying to connect Visual Studio(C#) to MySql database(phpmyadmin using WAMP).

I am getting this error : [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Because I am using phpmyadmin, I installed SSMS to configure SQL Server Services(which can be solution to my problem), but when I try to find server name in phpmyadmin as sql query : SELECT @@SERVICENAME,
I am getting another error: MySQL said: Documentation

## 1193 - Unknown system variable 'SERVERNAME'.

Can You help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Go to youtube and see how connect to mysql db from c#

Comment: You need install .net mysql connector first

Comment: @Breakermind I already have connector. I would like to know first, why this query wont work ?

Comment: From mysql page https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Variable does not exist in mysql propably

Comment: @Breakermind thanks for effort. i suggest writing possible solution in one post. missing connector could be an answer, but 'variable doesnt exist' after I writing 'unknown system variable', more look like mean answer, than help. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to connect to MySQL using SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)? You can't connect a MySQL database using SSMS.

For MySQL, you can use MySQL Workbench or you can check this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-MySQL-client-for-Mac-OS-X-or-Windows)

The `SELECT @@SERVICENAME, @@SERVERNAME` is a built-in function used by SQL Server not MySQL.

Comment: thank You! This clue led me to answer. I didnt know there is difference between Sql Server and MySql, so I just had to change SqlServerAdapter to MySqlServerAdapter. Btw, sorry for late response.